# got issue to control width in container

Tags: flutter, dart

I got problem to handle width in this container. It become to small and overlapping on other container. Image bellow as your reference.

[image]

And refer bellow code as your reference.... ..

```
Container(
        width: 660.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        child: Row(children: [
            Column(children: [
                Container(
                    width: 90.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                            "Serial Number",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                    width: 400.0,
                    height: 30.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius:
                        new BorderRadius.circular(2.0)),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 15,
                            right: 5,
                            top: 2,
                            bottom: 2),
                        child: TextFormField(
                            // initialValue: '',
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                        )),
                ),
            ]),
        ]),
    ),

    Container(
        width: data.size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
        child: Scrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text('1',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color:
                                    Colors.white))),
                        height: 40,
                        width: 306,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1.0,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            color: Colors.grey[600])),
                    Table(
                        defaultColumnWidth:
                        FixedColumnWidth(
                            data.size.width * 0.1),
                        border: TableBorder.all(
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[500]),
                        children: [
                            TableRow(
                                children: [
                                    "A",
                                    "B",
                                    "C",
                                    "D"
                                ]
                                .map((label) =>
                                    Container(
                                        height: 40,
                                        color: Colors
                                        .black,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets
                                        .symmetric(
                                            vertical:
                                            4),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                                label,
                                                textAlign:
                                                TextAlign
                                                .center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors
                                                    .white),
                                            ))))
                                .toList()),
                            ...this.rowList.map((row) {
                                return TableRow(
                                    children: [
                                        'valueA',
                                        'valueB',
                                        'valueC',
                                        'valueD'
                                    ]
                                    .map((label) =>
                                        Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors
                                                .white),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets
                                            .symmetric(
                                                vertical:
                                                4),
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                initialValue: row['1'][label],
                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                    row['1'][label] =
                                                        value;
                                                    print(
                                                        row);
                                                    print(row[
                                                        '1']);
                                                    updateDetails();
                                                },
                                                cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                    border:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    focusedBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    enabledBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    errorBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    disabledBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    isDense:
                                                    true,
                                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        horizontal:
                                                        4,
                                                        vertical:
                                                        4),
                                                ),
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))))
                                    .toList());
                            }).toList()
                        ]),
                    Container(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text('2',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color:
                                    Colors.white))),
                        height: 40,
                        width: 306,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1.0,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            color: Colors.grey[600])),
                    Table(
                        defaultColumnWidth:
                        FixedColumnWidth(
                            data.size.width * 0.1),
                        border: TableBorder.all(
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[500]),
                        children: [
                            TableRow(
                                children: [
                                    "A",
                                    "B",
                                    "C",
                                    "D"
                                ]
                                .map((label) =>
                                    Container(
                                        height: 40,
                                        color: Colors
                                        .black,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets
                                        .symmetric(
                                            vertical:
                                            4),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                                label,
                                                textAlign:
                                                TextAlign
                                                .center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors
                                                    .white),
                                            ))))
                                .toList()),
                            ...this.rowList.map((row) {
                                return TableRow(
                                    children: [
                                        'valueA',
                                        'valueB',
                                        'valueC',
                                        'valueD'
                                    ]
                                    .map((label) =>
                                        Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors
                                                .white),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets
                                            .symmetric(
                                                vertical:
                                                4),
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                initialValue: row['2'][label],
                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                    row['2'][label] =
                                                        value;
                                                    print(
                                                        row);
                                                    print(row[
                                                        '2']);
                                                    updateDetails();
                                                },
                                                cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                    border:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    focusedBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    enabledBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    errorBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    disabledBorder:
                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                    isDense:
                                                    true,
                                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        horizontal:
                                                        4,
                                                        vertical:
                                                        4),
                                                ),
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))))
                                    .toList());
                            }).toList()
                        ]),
                ])
            ))),

]);
```

Thanks in advance...

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fash I have reviewed your code as per my understanding and have wrapped the row in a `SingleChildScrollView` to enable horizontal scrolling. Use `expanded` to allow the first container to occupy the remaining vertical space. Adjust the width value as needed to avoid any overlap. I think this will help!